# Как узнать местоположение курсора в определённом элементе?

Tags: javascript, html

Я разрабатываю онлайн-рисовалку и мне надо знать, в какой части canvas*-а* (а он не на весь экран) находиться курсор (а я и размер полотна узнать немогу **:(** ).

P.s. Вот иллюстрация, чтоб вам было понятней:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Получить абсолютные коодинаты курсора window.event.x; window.event.y;
2. Получить абсолютные координаты левого верхнего угла области рисования. Наверное они есть в css или прописаны прямо в <div>
3. Вычесть из (1) (2)

А вообще Flash для таких вещей в разы лучше чем Javascript. [Пруфлник](http://pixlr.com/editor/)

Answer (score 4):

Так:

```
function position(event) {
var x = y = 0;
if (document.attachEvent != null) {
x = event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ?    document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft);
y = event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
} else if (!document.attachEvent && document.addEventListener) {
x = event.clientX + scrollX;
y = event.clientY + scrollY;
} else {}
return {x: x,y: y};
}
```